# Javascript Date comparison is bizarre

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I feel like this should live on a code golf post but the following behaviour caused a strange bug and is superficially unfathomable:

```
(a = new Date()) < (b = new Date())
a  // Thu Feb 11 2016 12:24:19 GMT+0000 (GMT)
b  // Thu Feb 11 2016 12:24:19 GMT+0000 (GMT)
a < b    // false (correct)
a === b  // false (incorrect)  <<<
a > b    // false (correct)
a <= b   // true (correct)
a >= b   // true (correct)
```

** **Edit** **
Where is this documented please?

Comment: … your question being why this was so?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ors21sd6/ Interesting, indeed.

Comment: Could this occur because `>=` compares the raw numbers associated with the `Date` while `===` checks for object equality?

Comment: They are not the same objects so `===` make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: @Hacketo I thought that too, but `{a:1} === {a:1}` is `false`...

Comment: @Hacketo that's not true

Comment: @Hacketo those are strings, not objects. Comparing primitives and objects are different

Comment: Regarding "*Where is this documented*", you need to look at the [*ECMAScript 2015*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) algorithms for the operators involved, namely *Abstract Relational Comparison* for `<` and `>`, *Abstract Equality Comparison* for `==` and *Strict Equality Comparison* for `===`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your comparisions other than the `===` one are coercing the dates to numbers (their time values, milliseconds since The Epoch) and then comparing those numbers. The `===` comparison is checking if `a` and `b` refer to **the same object**. (`==` would do the same thing.)

The times are (in your example) exactly the same, but there are still two distinct objects. Hence the results you're seeing.

Annotated:

```
// Create two Date instances, check if a's time value is less than b's
// (probably not, but it's just feasible this could cross a millisecond
// threshold)
(a = new Date()) < (b = new Date())

// Show the value of a and b
a  // Thu Feb 11 2016 12:24:19 GMT+0000 (GMT)
b  // Thu Feb 11 2016 12:24:19 GMT+0000 (GMT)

// See if a's time value is less than b's
a < b    // false

// See if a and b refer to the same object (they don't)
a === b  // false

// See if a's time value is greater than b's
a > b    // false

// See if a's time value is less than or equal to b's
a <= b   // true

// See if a's time value is greater than or equal to b's
a >= b
```

Or to put it another way, your code was basically doing this (note where the `+` signs are and aren't):

```
(a = new Date()) < (b = new Date())
a  // Thu Feb 11 2016 12:24:19 GMT+0000 (GMT)
b  // Thu Feb 11 2016 12:24:19 GMT+0000 (GMT)
+a < +b    // false
a === b    // false
+a > +b    // false
+a <= +b   // true
+a >= +b
```

Note that if the times are exactly the same, `+a === +b` (or `+a == +b`, or — being tricky — `+a == b` or `a == +b`) would all be true, because we'd be comparing time values.

Just for fun, here's an example where we know the underlying time values are exacty the same:

```js
var a, b;
var now = Date.now(); // = +new Date(); on old browsers
show("create and compare: ", (a = new Date(now)) < (b = new Date(now)), "a's time is not < b's");
show("+a < +b:   ", +a < +b,   "a's time is not < b's");
show("a < b:     ", a < b,     "a's time is not < b's");
show("a === b:   ", a === b,   "a and b don't refer to the same object");
show("a == b:    ", a == b,    "a and b don't refer to the same object");
show("+a === +b: ", +a === +b, "their time values are the same");
show("+a == +b:  ", +a == +b,  "their time values are the same");
show("+a > +b:   ", +a > +b,   "a's time is not > b's");
show("a > b:     ", a > b,     "a's time is not > b's");
show("+a <= +b:  ", +a <= +b,  "a's time is equal to b's");
show("a <= b:    ", a <= b,    "a's time is equal to b's");
show("+a >= +b:  ", +a >= +b,  "a's time is equal to b's   ");
show("a >= b:    ", a >= b,    "a's time is equal to b's   ");

function show(prefix, result, because) {
    var msg = prefix + result + ", " + because;
    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.innerHTML = msg.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
    document.body.appendChild(pre);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare dates you need to use `.getTime()`. So the correct comparison should be:

```
a.getTime() === b.getTime() //true
a.getTime() > b.getTime()   //false
...
```

Comment: `a < b` is same as `a.getTime() < b.getTime()`or `+a < +b`

Comment: That's because the date is equal: `new Date().getTime() === new Date().getTime()` is `true`. `getTime()` is indeed the correct way as also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: @Mark— `a.getTime() < b.getTime()` is identical to `a < b`. Both compare the time value.